# how to divide each one element from a column to each element of other column?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, paste

I have two column in one file :

```
1 2  
3 5  
4 8  
9 18  
3 5  
4 19
```

I want to divide each element of first column to each element of second column and want to print that number too.
for example:

```
1,2,1/2,  
1,5,1/5,  
1,8,1/8,  
1,18,1/18,  
1,19,1/19,  
3,5,3/5,  
4,19,4/19,  
3,2,3/2,  
3,5,3/8,  
3,19,3/19 and so on...
```

Please help me How can i proceed ?

Comment: You need to read each column into an array, then have a nested loop to print the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### GNU Parallel

```
parallel echo "{1},{2}" :::: <(cut -d' ' -f1 file) :::: <(cut -d' ' -f2 file) |
awk -F, '{ print $1,$2,$1"/"$2,$1/$2 }' OFS=, OFMT='%.2g'
```

Output:

```
1,2,1/2,0.5
1,5,1/5,0.2
1,8,1/8,0.12
1,18,1/18,0.056
1,5,1/5,0.2
1,19,1/19,0.053
3,2,3/2,1.5
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,8,3/8,0.38
3,18,3/18,0.17
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,19,3/19,0.16
4,2,4/2,2
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,8,4/8,0.5
4,18,4/18,0.22
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,19,4/19,0.21
9,2,9/2,4.5
9,5,9/5,1.8
9,8,9/8,1.1
9,18,9/18,0.5
9,5,9/5,1.8
9,19,9/19,0.47
3,2,3/2,1.5
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,8,3/8,0.38
3,18,3/18,0.17
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,19,3/19,0.16
4,2,4/2,2
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,8,4/8,0.5
4,18,4/18,0.22
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,19,4/19,0.21
```

Comment: how to run this script

Comment: @daizy123: replace `file` with your input file

Comment: it is working. one more question. if my columns are not equal means one contain 1000 data second column contain 567 data . because if data in columns are not equal it is not working

Comment: and suppose I have three column but I want third column to print as it is. How change in it.

Comment: @daizy123: look it up in the `cut` manual page

Answer (score 0):

This bash script snippet reads a text file called `numbers.txt` as formatted in your question and outputs a CSV, separated by colons, each line in the format:

```
Dividend;divisor;fraction;decimal
```

For the decimal calculation, it uses the tool `bc`.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a Dividend Divisor
while read -r Line; do
  if [ -n "$Line" ]; then
    Dividends+=("${Line%% *}")
    s="${Line#* }"
    Divisors+=("${s%% *}")
  fi
done < test.txt
for dividend in "${Dividends[@]}"; do
  for divisor in "${Divisors[@]}"; do
    echo "$dividend;$divisor;$dividend/$divisor;$(bc <<<"scale=5; $dividend/$divisor")"
  done
done
```

### How does it work?

It reads in the entire file into the two arrays `Dividends` and `Divisors` and iterates over them in nested loops (full Cartesian product). In this way, each dividend is divided by each divisor.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3

```
rows = open("file.txt", "r").read().split("\n")
for r in rows[:-1]:
    r = r.split(" ")
    print("%s,%s,%s/%s,%.2f" % (r[0], r[1], r[0], r[1], int(r[0])/int(r[1])))
```

For **file.txt**:

```
1 2
3 5
4 8
9 18
3 5
4 19
```

you will get:

```
1,2,1/2,0.50
3,5,3/5,0.60
4,8,4/8,0.50
9,18,9/18,0.50
3,5,3/5,0.60
4,19,4/19,0.21
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With bash brace-expansion and awk

```
c1="{$(cut -d' ' -f1 file | paste -sd,)}"
c2="{$(cut -d' ' -f2 file | paste -sd,)}"
echo echo $c1,$c2                     | 
bash                                  | 
tr ' ' '\n'                           |
awk -F, '{ print $0, $1"/"$2, $1/$2 }' OFS=, OFMT='%.2g'
```

Output:

```
1,2,1/2,0.5
1,5,1/5,0.2
1,8,1/8,0.12
1,18,1/18,0.056
1,5,1/5,0.2
1,19,1/19,0.053
3,2,3/2,1.5
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,8,3/8,0.38
3,18,3/18,0.17
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,19,3/19,0.16
4,2,4/2,2
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,8,4/8,0.5
4,18,4/18,0.22
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,19,4/19,0.21
9,2,9/2,4.5
9,5,9/5,1.8
9,8,9/8,1.1
9,18,9/18,0.5
9,5,9/5,1.8
9,19,9/19,0.47
3,2,3/2,1.5
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,8,3/8,0.38
3,18,3/18,0.17
3,5,3/5,0.6
3,19,3/19,0.16
4,2,4/2,2
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,8,4/8,0.5
4,18,4/18,0.22
4,5,4/5,0.8
4,19,4/19,0.21
```

Comment: where to give file name? I have wrote down this script in one file. After that I made that file executable. where to give input file name like Glyc.txt in script. I am running this script using ./executable script

Comment: @daizy123: replace `file` with your input file